# Make Invalid Validation Disappear After 5 Seconds --ReactJS--

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make the invalid feedback validation disappear after being on the screen for 5 seconds. in my state i have an empty errors object, when the form is submitted, the api call catches any errors from the backend, and they are placed in the errors object, the inputs use conditionals based on the errors object to show the validation. I've tried creating a setTimeout function that sets the state to an empty object after 5 seconds, but this causes breaking glitches if the form is submitted again incorrectly. Any insights how I can do this?

Register.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import classnames from 'classnames';
class Register extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      password2: "",
      errors: {}
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    // THIS FUNCTION MUST BE BOUND -SEE ABOVE BIND
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }
  onSubmit = e => {
    // ARROW FUNCTIONS DO NOT NEED TO BE BOUND
    e.preventDefault();
    const newUser = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      password2: this.state.password2
    };
    this.setState({
      email: "",
      name: "",
      password: "",
      password2: ""
    });
    axios
      .post("/api/users/register", newUser)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .catch(err => this.setState({ errors: err.response.data }));
  };

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="register">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
                <h1 className="display-4 text-center text-dark">Sign Up</h1>
                <p className="lead text-center">Create your DevMuse account</p>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className={classnames("form-control form-control-lg", {
                        "is-invalid": errors.name
                      })}
                      placeholder="Name"
                      name="name"
                      value={this.state.name}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                    {errors.name && (
                      <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.name}</div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      className={classnames("form-control form-control-lg", {
                        "is-invalid": errors.email
                      })}
                      placeholder="Email Address"
                      name="email"
                      value={this.state.email}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />

                    {errors.email ? (
                      <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.email}</div>
                    ) : (
                      <small className="form-text text-muted text-center">
                        This site uses Gravatar so if you want a profile image,
                        use a Gravatar email
                      </small>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                      type="password"
                      className={classnames("form-control form-control-lg", {
                        "is-invalid": errors.password
                      })}
                      placeholder="Password"
                      name="password"
                      value={this.state.password}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                    {errors.password && (
                      <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.password}</div>
                    )}
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                      type="password"
                      className={classnames("form-control form-control-lg", {
                        "is-invalid": errors.password2
                      })}
                      placeholder="Confirm Password"
                      name="password2"
                      value={this.state.password2}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                    {errors.password2 && (
                      <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.password2}</div>
                    )}

                  </div>
                  <input
                    type="submit"
                    className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4"
                  />
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just clear any existing timeout before you initiate a new timeout:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearTimeout(this.clearError);
}

...

.catch((err) => {
  this.setState({ errors: err.response.data });

  clearTimeout(this.clearError); // clear previous timeout, if exists
  this.clearError = setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ errors: {} });
  }, 5000);
});
```